# Anonymous function called : "Fatal error: Function name must be a string"

Tags: php, dependency-injection, anonymous-function

this is my class "container" for dependency Injection.

When I call $this->get($service), I have "Fatal error: Function name must be a string".

I set the service ($this->set($service)) before but all the time the same problem.

An idea ?

```
<?php

namespace Core;

class Container {

    private $_container             = array();
    private $_containerSingleton    = array();

    public function __construct(ServicesInterface $services){
        $this->_initServicesFromConfiguration($services->get());
    }

    private function _initServicesFromConfiguration($services){
        foreach ($services as $service){
            $this->set($service);
        }
    }

    public function set($service){
        $this->_container[$service] = function() use ($service) {
                                    return new $service();
                                  };
    }

    public function get($service){
        return $this->_container[$service]();
    }

    public function share($service){
        if(isset($this->_containerSingleton[$service])){
            return $this->_containerSingleton[$service];
        }
        $this->_containerSingleton[$service] = $this->get($service);
        return $this->_containerSingleton[$service];
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Question: why the closure? `$this->_container[$service] = new $service;` wouldn't have worked for you?

Comment: I want instantiate my service only when I call my service ($this->get method) and not when I set the service. ($this->set method).

With closure, I just define the creation of my object but I don't instantiate it.

Comment: `function(){ return new $service(); };` and `new $service;` is not equivalent.
I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now